# Best way to provide navigation similar to wordpress

Tags: navigation

What is the recommended way to setup navigation, in a similar way to Wordpress?
So that certain pages or channels can be added, and some may be excluded from the navigation.

Also, what if I want to add a sub-navigation menu on a page to show the child pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend going with a "Structure". This would be the build in way of doing it. You can setup the Structure to have it's own fields to control different "Pages" OR you can have it only use a related entries field and link to other entries anyway you like.

This topic has been discussed quite a lot and you have some great posts here:

- [Would you use a Structure as navigation over multiple sections (channel entries, indexes and singles)?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/would-you-use-a-structure-as-navigation-over-multiple-sections-channel-entries)
- [Multi-lingual site navigation made of singles, channels and structure](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/883/multi-lingual-site-navigation-made-of-singles-channels-and-structure)
- [How do you handle complex navigation in Craft?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1834/how-do-you-handle-complex-navigation-in-craft)

There's also "Plugin" solutions out there like https://github.com/am-impact/amnav.